# No mysqli result inside while loop for batch upload

Tags: php, excel, mysqli

I am trying to make a batch upload function to add users to the database. I have a function which adds a single user's details to the db, and I call it from inside a while loop which reads from an excel sheet:

```
$excel = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
$excel->read($target_file);

        $company = mysql_prep($_POST["company"]);

while($x<=$excel->sheets[0]['numRows']) {
            $username = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][1]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][1] : '';
            $email = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][2]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][2] : '';

            //generate random password
            $password = generate_random_password();

            //hash the password
            $hashed_password = password_encrypt($password);
            $status = "Employee";

            //save details in db
            $result = add_single_user($username, $hashed_password, $email, $status, $company); }
```

The function add_single_user returns a result when called from outside this loop, but won't insert a user as shown above. I have checked that the values are being read by the excel reader and being assigned. Here is the function:

```
function add_single_user($username, $hashed_password, $email, $status, $company){
global $connection;
$safe_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $username);
$safe_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $email);
$safe_status = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $status);
$safe_company = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $company);

$query  = "INSERT INTO users (";
$query .= "  username, hashed_password, email, status, company";
$query .= ") VALUES (";
$query .= "  '{$safe_username}', '{$hashed_password}', '{$safe_email}', '{$safe_status}', '{$safe_company}'";
$query .= ")";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
return $result;
```

}

Comment: Simple debug/troubleshooting first: Just before your mysqli_query executes, echo your $query string to to your screen/browser. If it shows the sql you expect - then copy/paste into your php admin SQL window and test it

Comment: @dbmitch Thank you. I had tried copy/pasting it in before but this is a much better way of troubleshooting. There was a restriction on one of the database fields that I didn't realise was there. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For an INSERT query, `mysqli_query` should return either `true` or `false`.

Assuming `$connection` actually contains the object for the DB connection, the query should work (apart from the curly brackets in the VALUES part that will probably be inserted into the DB).

Try to see if `mysqli_connect_error()` or `mysqli_error()` comunicate an error in the connection or in the query (It's a good practice anyway to control if there is any error in establishing a connection to the DB and in executing queries).

Besides, I wuold suggest you to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using mysql_prep, real_escape_string and mysqli_query, as they are not effective against injection.